# GitLab for CentOS i386

Tags: gitlab, rpm, centos6, i386

I want to install GitLab for my CentOS v.6 i386. [Official web site](https://about.gitlab.com/) provides x86_64 RPM version only. 
Could you please suggest, where I can find GitLab or some analogues for i386 CentOS system?

Thanks

Comment: If they don't provide it you get to build it yourself from their sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support team has provided the [instructions](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/build.md#centos-6-5) for building gitlab for CentOS from sources